# Angular4 método editar

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Comecei no angular4 a pouco tempo, preciso pegar as informações de um campo e passar pra tela de edit, eu ja tenho essas informações em um console.log da tela edit que eu botei pra testar, único problema é que n to conseguindo exibir nos campos, talvez seria o decorator Input mas nao to conseguindo utilizá-lo, alguma ajuda?

eu tenho essa condição se caso o ID tiver definido ele busca no service o regioesById pra rota editar, eu ja tenho o id na rota também oque falta é exibir, segue codigo:

```
 if (this.route.snapshot.params['id'] != undefined) {
      this.regiaoService.regioesById(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
        .subscribe(
          regioes => {
            this.regioes = regioes
            this.idRegioes = regioes.codigoregiao
            console.log(this.regioes);
        })
    }
```

eu declaro antes do construtor essa variavel que recebe as regioes:

regioes : Regioes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente o que você precisa é informar a diretiva [`ngModel`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) no campo e ou [`ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) caso a variável contenha um array.

```html
<input type="text" [ngModel]="regioes">
<input type="text" [ngModel]="idRegioes">
```

Sendo um array:

```html
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let regiao of regioes" value="{{regiao.id}}">{{regiao.nome}}</option>
</select>
```

#### Referência

- [`ngModel`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)
- [`ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

Comment: Eu já havia resolvido, mas você está certo wmsouza, foi desse jeito que eu resolvi, de qualquer forma obrigado :))